# Hide/show child element onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a *"edit profile"* page.

Here is what I want to do:

1. In each section, the employer will be shown and the edit form will be hidden.
2. When I click the *"edit employer"* button, the edit form will be shown and the employer will be hidden.

Here is what I did using jQuery. It does not work when I click on the *"edit employer"* button. I do not know why this does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="edit">
            <form class="editForm">
                employer: <input type="text" value="Citigroup" />
            </form>
            <div class="contents">Employer: Citigroup</div>
            <button class="editButton">Edit Employer</button>
        </div>

        <script>
            $('div.edit').each(function(i) {
                $(this).children('.editForm').hide();
            })
            $('div.edit').each(function() {
                $(this).children('.editButton').click(function() {
                    $(this).children('.editForm').show();
                    $(this).children('.contents').hide();
                });
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `this` inside the click handler is not the same as in the each. In the click, it refers to the .editButton element.

Comment: `.editButton` don't have children. `$(this)` inside event handler refer to the button that is clicked. Use `$(this).siblings('.editForm').show().siblings('.contents).hide()`

Comment: Welcome. Avoid using `each`, jQuery does that for you. `$('div.edit .editForm').hide();` or better, use CSS to hide elements. And to bind event `$('div.edit .editButton').click(function () { ... });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(this)` inside the `click` function contains the local instance of the `$(this).children('.editButton')`. For that reason your code is not finding any `.editForm` elements.

For this to work you could do something like this:

```
<script>
    $('div.edit').each(function(i) {
        $(this).children('.editForm').hide();
    })
    $('div.edit').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $(this).children('.editButton').click(function() {
            $this.children('.editForm').show();
            $this.children('.contents').hide();
        });
    })
</script>
```

If I may I would improve the code with some more changes:

```
<script>
    $('.edit .editForm').hide(); // this will hide all instances of .editForm
    $('.edit .editButton').click(function() { //assign 1 handler for all cases
       $(this).siblings('.editForm').show(); // show the sibling edit form
       $(this).siblings('.contents').hide(); // hide the sibling contents element
    });
</script>
```

Reference: 
Sibling Selector: https://api.jquery.com/siblings/#siblings-selector

Comment: Very clean solution. I like it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I helped if you liked it accept it as an answer :P

Comment: You can check here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `this` inside the click handler referring to the button, not the `div.edit`. Here's one way to fix this:

```js
$('div.edit').each(function(i) {
  $(this).children('.editForm').hide();
});
$('div.edit').each(function() {
  var $self = $(this);
  $(this).children('.editButton').click(function() {
    $self.children('.editForm').show();
    $self.children('.contents').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edit">
  <form class="editForm">
    employer:
    <input type="text" value="Citigroup" />
  </form>
  <div class="contents">Employer: Citigroup</div>
  <button class="editButton">Edit Employer</button>
</div>
```

Comment: And this code can be [improved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363783/hide-show-child-element-on-click-in-jquery#comment69929040_41363783). `each` can be avoided.

Comment: @Tushar If I have many sections on the page (different employers, schools), how do you avoid each?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `.each()` at all.  Just do an `.click()` event on the class of `.editButton` and use `this` to find its parent.  If you want to make a toggle, you're going to have to make use of a new class or something of that nature to make a conditional statement off of.

```
//This will hide *ANY* .editForm elements
$('.editForm').hide();

//This will fire off of *ANY* editButton clicks.
$('.editButton').click(function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('.edit');             //Get the wrapper
    if(form.hasClass('open')) {                      //Check to see if it is open or not
        form.removeClass('open').addClass('close');  //Toggle Classes
        form.find('.editForm').show();
        form.find('.contents').hide();
    } else {
        form.removeClass('close').addClass('open');
        form.find('.editForm').hide();
        form.find('.contents').show();
    }
});
```

I like to use `closest` and `find` more than `parent` and `children` (respectively).  They can go 1-many layers up or down and search the hierarchy for whatever you're looking for, rather than `parent` and `children` going up or down a single layer.

If you are inserting your `.edit` form after the DOM loads, you're going to need to bind your click event to the document

```
$(document).on('click', '.editButton', function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('.edit');
    form.find('.editForm').hide();
    form.find('.contents').show();
});
```